# Weak solution operator of Elliptic PDE is lower bounded or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, elliptic-equations

I am interested in the operator $T: v\mapsto u$ where $u$ is the weak solution of the following well-studied Elliptic PDE
\begin{align}
-\text{div} (A\nabla u) &=v \text{ in } \Omega,\\
u & =0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega.
\end{align}
Here, for each $x\in \Omega$, $A(x)$ is a symmetric matrix such that, exists $c>0$, $y^TA(x)y>c||y||^2_2$ for all vector $y$.

It is well known that the operator $T$ is upper bounded (continuous). I am wondering if it is lower bounded or not, i.e. does there exist a constant $\gamma>0$ such that
\begin{align}
||T v||\geq \gamma ||v|| \text{ for all } v.
\end{align}

I know that an operator is lower bounded iff it is injective and has closed range (see Theorem 2.5 [here](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-50)). However, since I am not familiar with PDE, I don't know where to begin. Could any one give me some clues to prove it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this operator is not lower bounded in your sense. If it were, we would have
$$
\gamma \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2\leq c\gamma\int_\Omega A\nabla u\cdot\nabla u=c\gamma\int_\Omega vu\leq c\gamma\|u\|_2\|v\|_2\leq c\|u\|_2^2
$$
for $u\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. To see that this is not true, take any $u\in L^2(\Omega)\setminus H^1(\Omega)$ and a sequence $(u_n)$ in $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $u_n\to u$ in $L^2$.